# Opening the wsp file in Visual Studio for Sharepoint Migration

Tags: migration

I am trying to open wsp file in visual studio but it was asking me to install Sharepoint server which I dont want to do. I tried converting the wsp to .cab and extracted it, by doing that I was able to open the content files in notepad. But I was looking for a way to open all files(like opening all files by selecting only the .sln file for asp.net web applications) since the wsp file needs code change and we need to build the solution for deploying it. Please help me out as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

The wsp does not contain the sln. You can rename it to cab and extract it as you already mentionend. After extracting it you the the whole Content. Nothing else is included in the wsp.

Comment: ..Thank u Stefan. Now I have my extracted files to the folder. And I am able to only file by file in visual studio. Is there any way of opening all the files at once. And how can I build all the changes so that I can make a deploy-able file. Kindly explain (the procedure) to build and deploy. It would be so much helpful ! Thanks

Comment: Any response would be appreciable !